# Force the direction of the synonym relationship between [make] and [makefile]

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, tag-synonyms

So the fact is that [many users seem to tag questions about the veritable unix build manager](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/24030/2509) as [[tag:makefile]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/makefile) rather than the more consistent [[tag:make]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/make). (Because the *language* is make, and we don't tag things [c-source-file](/questions/tagged/c-source-file) or [ruby-script](/questions/tagged/ruby-script) or even [shell-script](/questions/tagged/shell-script) (though we *have* set a synonym with from [shell-script](/questions/tagged/shell-script) --> [shell](/questions/tagged/shell)).

And I'm sympathetic because I'd have done the same thing back in the day. But it really bugs me now. So this seems a perfect use case for tag synonyms, only when I try to set on with [make](/questions/tagged/make) as the master, I run into the highest usage heuristic.

**Arrgghhh!**

I am sorely tempted to launch into a large scale re-tagging just to "fix" the situation, but rather than preempt the community I ask the assembled masses: *"Can and should we make [make](/questions/tagged/make) the master?"*

---

See also [Are these really the tag synonyms we want?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/68183/2509)